# Microsoft Flow for 10 Approvers Chosen Randomly with sequential workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I am trying to build workflow in flow with 12 approvers.

Lets assume approver 1, approver 2, approver 3, approver 4, approver 5.....

Now when user choses to select approver 2 and approver 5 and approver 10  and approver 12.

I want to assign a workflow sequentially. Is it possible to do so in flow.

When i think about it it is going to be a nasty chain of conditions and action.

Can you think of better ways to execute this flow.

Answer (score 1):

An idea for this requirement:

In the approve flow, do a calculation to calculate Current Item ID mod `<the number of approvers>`:

For example, there are 12 approvers:

Calculate Current Item ID mod 12

- If the output value equals 1 (for example: 1 mod 12 = 1, 13 mod 12 = 1), assign approval task to approver1.
- If the output value equals 2 (for example: 2 mod 12 = 2, 14 mod 12 = 2), assign approval task to approver2.
- If the output value equals 3 (for example: 3 mod 12 = 3, 15 mod 12 = 3), assign approval task to approver3.
- ...
- If the output value equals 0 (for example: 12 mod 12 = 0, 24 mod 12 = 0), assign approval task to approver12.

Comment: But this is a sequential workflow workflow needs to step through each approval step in sequence correct . So it should try approver 1 first then 2 then 3 then 4 and so one? correct?

Comment: But this is a sequential workflow workflow needs to step through each approval step in sequence correct . So it should try approver 2 first then 5 then 10 then 12 and so one? correct? When user  select approver2, approver5, approver10, approver12 now flow should assign approval sequentiallay meaning, first approver 2, then wait until response is received from approver 2, if yes go to approver 5 for approver , if yes go to approver 10.

But user can just select any group of users, from 1-12 or all?